# WordPress/WooCommerce: Cannot Specify Product Category In WP_Query

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to set up a custom loop that cycles through products assigned to a product category, but it doesn't seem to be working.

My category setup:

Factory Direct
- FD1
- FD2
- FD3

I want my loop to display products that fall into ANY CHILDREN CATEGORIES of Factory Direct which has an ID of 84.

My attempt at coding this in my template:

```
<ul class="products factoryloop">
    <?php
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'product',
            'posts_per_page' => 12,
            'cat' => 84
            );
        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
        if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
            while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
                woocommerce_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
            endwhile;
        } else {
            echo __( 'No products found' );
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();
    ?>
</ul><!--/.products-->
```

I have tried changing the ID from 84 to a specific category (example FD1 which has an ID of 24), but it still isn't working.

Any ideas/suggestions?

It loops through products if I remove the cat argument in WP_Query, but I can't specify my loop.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to get all children of the category first and include them in the `cat` parameter in the query.

```
<ul class="products factoryloop">
    <?php
        $parentCat = 84;
        $children = get_categories(array('child_of'=>$parentCat));

        $childs = array($parentCat);
        foreach($children as $child){
            $childs[] = $child->cat_ID;
        }
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'product',
            'posts_per_page' => 12,
            'cat' => implode(',', $childs);
            );
        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
        if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
            while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
                woocommerce_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
            endwhile;
        } else {
            echo __( 'No products found' );
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();
    ?>
</ul><!--/.products-->
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did it with **query_posts**, you should do same thing with **WP_Query**.

```
function getCategoryByParent ($id) {
    $args=array(
      'orderby' => 'name',
      'parent' => $id,
      'hide_empty' => false,
      'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
      'order' => 'ASC',
      );
    $categories=get_categories($args);
    return $categories;
}
$cats = getCategoryByParent(84);
query_posts( array( 'paged' => $paged, 'posts_per_page' => 9, 'post_type' => 'product', 'post_status' => 'publish' ,  'taxonomy' => 'product_cat', 'tax_query' => array( 
            array(
              'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
              'field' => 'id',
              'terms' => $cats
            ))));
```

Hope you find it helpful, Asaf.